# How to display JS DataTable from a Pandas dataframe using the Pyramid web framerwork?

Tags: pandas, datatables, jinja2, pyramid

There are some examples of doing this with `Flask`, so this should theoretically be possible with `Pyramid` too, but so far, haven't been able to. I'm trying to get a Pandas dataframe displayed using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) JS library in the [Pyramid web framework](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html). Here's my folder/file structure:

```
repo_name/
    modules/
        get_df.py
    static/
        theme.css
    templates/
        layout.jinja2
        mytemplate.jinja2
    views/
        __init__.py
        default.py
    routes.py
development.ini
production.ini
setup.py
```

Most of these files are untouched from the Pyramid cookiecutter code [here](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter). But the files I edites are pasted below.

#### `views/default.py`

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from repo_name.modules.get_df import main

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='../templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    df = main()
    html_table = df.to_html(table_id='myTable')
    return dict(project='my_project', table=html_table)
```

#### `mytemplate.jinja2`

```
{% extends "layout.jinja2" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
  <h1><span class="font-semi-bold">Pyramid</span> <span class="smaller">Starter project</span></h1>
<!--   <p class="lead">Welcome to <span class="font-normal">{{project}}</span>, a&nbsp;Pyramid application generated&nbsp;by<br><span class="font-normal">Cookiecutter</span>.</p> -->
  <p class="lead">Welcome to <span class="font-normal">{{project}}</span>, a&nbsp;Pyramid application generated&nbsp;by<br><span class="font-normal">Cookiecutter</span>.</p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block additional_scripts %}
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/mytemplate.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

#### `layout.jinja2` (added CDNs for DataTables)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{request.locale_name}}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="pyramid web application">
    <meta name="author" content="Pylons Project">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{request.static_url('repo_name:static/pyramid-16x16.png')}}">

    <title>Cookiecutter Starter project for the Pyramid Web Framework</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this scaffold -->
    <link href="{{request.static_url('repo_name:static/theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- My: DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js" integrity="sha384-0s5Pv64cNZJieYFkXYOTId2HMA2Lfb6q2nAcx2n0RTLUnCAoTTsS0nKEO27XyKcY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZoaMbDF+4LeFxg6WdScQ9nnR1QC2MIRxA1O9KWEXQwns1G8UNyIEZIQidzb0T1fo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="starter-template">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{{request.static_url('repo_name:static/pyramid.png') }}" alt="pyramid web framework">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            {% block content %}
                <p>No content</p>
            {% endblock content %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="links">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon-muted"></i><a href="https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid">Github Project</a></li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe icon-muted"></i><a href="https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=pyramid">IRC Channel</a></li>
              <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon-muted"></i><a href="https://pylonsproject.org">Pylons Project</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="copyright">
            Copyright &copy; Pylons Project
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- My: DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


    {% block additional_scripts %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

The resulting webpage doesn't display the DataTable or the raw HTML table, it only displays the default HTML text with CSS formatting. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any HTML `<table>` that would render the data in your Jinja template. The data that gets passed into that template should be a Python dict. The example below assumes that you pass in the dict `users` to the template.

## views/default.py

```py
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='../templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    # insert function here that returns users as a Python dict
    return dict(project='my_project', users=users)
```

## mytemplate.jinja2

```
{% if users %}
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-orderable="false">Edit</th>
        <th data-orderable="false">Delete</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Role</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ request.route_url('user_edit', user_id=user['id']) }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="{{ request.route_url('user_delete', user_id=user['id']) }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>
        <td>{{ user['username'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ user['role'] }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% else %}
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No users found.</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sure, but my question is how do I pass the Pandas dataframe to the HTML jinja2 template and have it be read there by the JS DataTables library?

Comment: From my answer: "The data that gets passed into that template should be a Python dict."

Comment: I use it in a private application. You first need to pass data into your template so that it gets rendered as HTML to the client web browser. Then DataTables will work its magic on the rendered HTML client-side.

Comment: Can you show an example? That's exactly what I'm unable to get working and was asking for in my question.

Comment: See my example in my answer. What specifically is not clear? Do you at least see the HTML table rendered with your data? That is step 1.

Comment: If you look at my `views/default.py`, I'm returning the *table* in a dictionary, and then am trying to render that using DataTables JS library. However, in your example, you are returning a *list* which you are using on your page to render a HTML table, *not* a DataTable.

Comment: I have no idea what `to_html` does because you provide no code for it. You also don't have any variable in your template to accept the value of `table`. Obviously what you are doing does not work. Try the method in my example. It works for me.